# upload multiple photos using retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit, retrofit2, multipartform-data, multipart

I'm working on demo where user can click multiple photo and upload into server so i created list where i'm storing all images but while hitting API end Point i'm getting Exception.
gone through [multiple image upload using retrofit 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43034437/how-to-upload-multiple-images-in-one-request-using-retrofit-2-and-php-as-a-back) but unable to resolve issue.

here is my log cat :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: @Part annotation must supply a name or use MultipartBody.Part parameter type. (parameter #1)
        for method RetrofitInterface.uploadImages
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:720)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.methodError(ServiceMethod.java:711)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parameterError(ServiceMethod.java:729)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameterAnnotation(ServiceMethod.java:592)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.parseParameter(ServiceMethod.java:333)
        at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.build(ServiceMethod.java:202)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit.loadServiceMethod(Retrofit.java:166)
        at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Retrofit.java:145)
        at $Proxy0.uploadImages(Native Method)
        at com.example.innobles.imagesuploader.Remote.RetrofitClient.uploads(RetrofitClient.java:41)
```

RetrofitClient.java:

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://example.com/abc/application/";
    private static RetrofitClient retrofitClient;
    private static RetrofitInterface retrofitInterface;

    public static RetrofitInterface getRetrofitApi() {
        //return retrofit object
    }

    public static Call<ServerResponse> uploads( Map<String,MultipartBody.Part> images) {
        return getRetrofitApi().uploadImages(images);
    }
}
```

RetrofitInterface .java

```
public interface RetrofitInterface {
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload_images.php")
    Call<ServerResponse> uploadImages(@Part Map<String,MultipartBody.Part> images);
}
```

uploadImage method:

```
private void uploadImages(List<Uri> uriPaths) {
        Map<String,MultipartBody.Part> list = new HashMap<>();
        for (Uri uri : uriPaths) {
            MultipartBody.Part imageRequest = prepareFilePart("file[]", uri);
            list.put("images", imageRequest);
        }

        RetrofitClient.uploads(list).enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful() && response.body()!=null)
                    Log.e("MAIN", response.body().getMessage());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("main", "on error is called and the error is  ----> " + t.getMessage());

            }
        });


    }
```

Helper method:

```
  @NonNull
    private MultipartBody.Part prepareFilePart(String partName, Uri fileUri) {
        File file = new File(fileUri.getPath());
        RequestBody requestFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

        // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name
        return MultipartBody.Part.createFormData(partName, file.getName(), requestFile);
    }
```

where I'm doing wrong ? please help, I'm new to android.

Comment: [refer this link it will help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39489714/2794507)

Comment: @HardikVasani thank you man you save ma time . thanks once again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did solve ma problem like this:

In **RetrfitClient.java**  add **createRequestBody()** method and call  this method inside **uploadsImages(List uri)** method.

In RetrofitInterface.java:

replace  `Call<ServerResponse> uploadImages(@Part Map<String,MultipartBody.Part> images);` with  `Call<ServerResponse> uploadImages( @PartMap Map<String, RequestBody> files);`

createRequest method :

```
public static RequestBody createRequestBody(@NonNull File file){
        return RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"),file);
    }
```